# How to "convert" Task<> to google.api.services.drive.model.File?

Tags: java, google-drive-android-api

I'm at a beginner level and having trouble to use methods with different parameter and return types.

I've created a method to upload file to Google Drive (through the Drive REST API) and another method to search a Google Drive folder. The problem is that the return type from method of search folder is Task <*> and I'd like the found folder to be sent as parameter to the upload file method, it's just that the types of parameters are com.google.api.services.drive.model.File and AbstractInputStreamContent.

How should I "convert" a Task <*> object to File?

Here are the methods of search folder and upload file:

```
public Task<GoogleDriveFileHolder> searchFolder(String folderName) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            // Retrive the metadata as a File object.
            FileList result = mDriveService.files().list()
                    .setQ("mimeType = '" + "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"  + "' and name = '" + folderName + "' ")
                    .setSpaces("drive")
                    .execute();
            GoogleDriveFileHolder googleDriveFileHolder = new GoogleDriveFileHolder();
            if (result.getFiles().size() > 0) {
                googleDriveFileHolder.setId(result.getFiles().get(0).getId());
                googleDriveFileHolder.setName(result.getFiles().get(0).getName());
            }
            return googleDriveFileHolder;
        });
}

public Task<GoogleDriveFileHolder> uploadFile(File googleDiveFile, AbstractInputStreamContent content) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            // Retrieve the metadata as a File object.
            File fileMeta = mDriveService.files().create(googleDiveFile, content).execute();
            GoogleDriveFileHolder googleDriveFileHolder = new GoogleDriveFileHolder();
            googleDriveFileHolder.setId(fileMeta.getId());
            googleDriveFileHolder.setName(fileMeta.getName());
            return googleDriveFileHolder;
        });
}
```

Comment: What do you want to get after uploading a file? it's fileId?

Answer (score 0):

You do not "convert" it. A Task is a bit like Executors : they do background work.

You can add listeners to retrieve the result :

```
searchFolder("my folder")
    .addOnSuccessListener(...your listener...)
    .addOnFailureListener(...your other listener...);
```

Or you can execute the task synchronously in your own background executor :

```
 Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               FileList result = myDriveService.files().list().
                     ... .execute();
               //do something with your result
              }
 });
```

In that case, you will need to catch IOException yourself in the Runnable